# Interpolated heat map plot from discrete data points

Tags: matplotlib

I have a data set of discrete, sparse points (*x*, *y*, *value*). I'd like to plot the data so that every (*x*, *y*) coordinate is given a color based on interpolation between nearby data points.

```
data = np.array([
    [0, 0, 18.75],
    [0, 2, 0],
    [0, 4, 16],
    [0, 6, 2],
    [-4, 2, 18],
    [-4, 4, 35],
    [-4, 6, 32],
    [-4, 8, 15],
    [-4, 10, 28],
    [4, 0, 26],
    [4, 2, 30],
    [4, 4, 32],
    [4, 6, 35],
    [4, 8, 26.5],
])
```

I've tried using `pcolormesh` but it expects my `C` values are a 2D array. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I adapted an [example of `scipy.interpolate.griddata`](https://scipython.com/book/chapter-8-scipy/examples/two-dimensional-interpolation-with-scipyinterpolategriddata/), with `plt.contourf()` as suggested by Matt Pitkin:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from scipy.interpolate import griddata


x, y, vals = data[:,0], data[:,1], data[:,2]

X, Y = np.meshgrid(
    np.linspace(np.min(x), np.max(x), 100),
    np.linspace(np.min(y), np.max(y), 100)
)

interpolated_vals = griddata((x, y), vals, (X, Y), method='cubic')

plt.contourf(X, Y, interpolated_vals)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [`contourf`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.contourf.html#matplotlib.pyplot.contourf) and doing the following:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# create mesh grid for x/y-data
grid = np.meshgrid(data[:,0], data[:,1])

# create 2D array of z-values
vals = np.zeros((len(data), len(data)))
for row in data:
    vals[(grid[0] == row[0]) & (grid[1] == row[1])] = row[2]

# create contour plot
plt.contourf(data[:, 0], data[:, 1], vals)
```

Comment: Hm, the plot I get is scrambled. Do you have a screenshot you could attach of what this looks like for you?

Comment: My output looks quite scrambled too, but to be honest I wasn't sure what to expect given the data. You could try transposing the `vals` array in case that makes a difference.